# Java GrayLog Integration Using Gelf

Tags: java, log4j, log4net-appender, graylog

I want to do graylog integration in java by using "gelf" library. I added config parameters in order to connect graylog server into "log4j_Appender.xml"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="info" packages="org.graylog2.log4j2">
     <Appenders>
      <GELF name="gelfAppender" server="graylog.llm.com" port="12212" hostname="llmtest.llm.com" protocol="UDP" includeThreadContext="true">
       <KeyValuePair key="grayloggroup" value="LLMFIGHTTEST" />
       <KeyValuePair key="application" value="baggagebustest" />
       <KeyValuePair key="environment" value="baggagebustest" />

    <!--    <Filters> -->
    <!--     <Filter type="MakerFilter" marker="FLOW" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"></Filter> -->
    <!--     <Filter type="MakerFilter" marker="EXCEPTION" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"></Filter> -->
    <!--    </Filters> -->
       <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
      </GELF>
     </Appenders>
     <Loggers>
      <Root level="info">
       <AppenderRef ref="gelfAppender" />
      </Root>
     </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

But I can not connect to "graylog.llm.com"  and I don't add a log into "LLMFIGHTTEST" stream.

I am using [this](https://github.com/graylog-labs/log4j2-gelf) project in github.

Comment: Is there an error that you receive when trying to connect to "graylog.llm.com"?

Comment: I don't have any error or exception about connect to server. "client.trySend(gelfMessage)" The code  returned is true. But I don't see my message which sended on graylog interface.

Answer (score 0):

We should use add appender into log4j.xml file and add dependency log4j2-gelf as maven dependency.

```
Dependency,

<dependency> <groupId>org.graylog2.log4j2</groupId> <artifactId>log4j2-gelf</artifactId> <version>1.3.2-SNAPSHOT</version> </dependency>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" packages="org.graylog2.log4j2">
 <Appenders>
  <GELF name="gelfAppender" server="graylog.test.com" port="12212" hostname="test.th.com" protocol="UDP" includeThreadContext="true">

    <KeyValuePair key="ORDERID" value="$${ctx:ORDERID}"/>

   <Filters>
    <Filter type="MakerFilter" marker="PARENT" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"></Filter>
    <Filter type="MakerFilter" marker="TEST" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"></Filter>
   </Filters>
  <PatternLayout pattern="ORDERID : $${ctx:ORDERID} %msg%n"  />

  </GELF>
  <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
   <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%level] [%thread] [%c{1.}] - %m%n" />
  </Console>
 </Appenders>
 <Loggers>
  <Root level="info">
   <AppenderRef ref="gelfAppender" />
   <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
    <AppenderRef ref="Error-Appender" level="error"/>
  </Root>
 </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```